# Ionic - ion-nav-view crashes in emulator

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a problem when I try to use ion-nav-view. When I try to use it, it shows me black screen in the emulator but in ionic serve, it works perfectly for me.

I think it is a syntax error.

Also, when I create a blank project, it works perfectly in the emulator.

My project (doesn't work)
[image: My Project]

Blank project (does work)
[image: Blank Project]

Index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>


    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter" animation="slide-left-right-ios7">
    <ion-nav-bar></ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

/templates/apps/index.html

```
<ion-view title="Hello World">
    <ion-content>
        <h2>Hello World</h2>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

app.js

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
// 'starter.services' is found in services.js
// 'starter.controllers' is found in controllers.js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
  // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
  // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
  // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
  $stateProvider

    // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('apps', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: '/templates/apps/index.html'
    });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallbac
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to make your `templateUrl: 'templates/apps/index.html'`. The forward slash makes the path absolute, which will work on `ionic serve` because its a web server running at the root of the domain. It doesn't work in app because files are loaded over the file:// protocol and are not at the root, so it might crash because you are referencing a file that doesn't exist and would be outside of the app and thus perhaps a permission issue.